# Logout not working in laravel5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

It does not destroy the session after logout I able to see the dashboard.How to use Auth mechanism in my View controller

**Controller**

```
public function admin_logout()
{
    Session::forget('userid');
    Session::forget('username');
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect('siteadmin');
}
```

**Model**

```
 public static function login_check($uname,$password)
    {
        $check = DB::table('le_admin')->where('adm_email','=',$uname)->where('adm_password','=',$password)->get();
    if($check)
    {
        Session::put('userid', $check[0]->adm_id);
        Session::put('username', $check[0]->adm_email);
        return 1;

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
Auth::logout()
```

to make sure user is logged out.

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: In Auth file i  need to write any coding for logout

Comment: No, it will use default mechanism. In your `admin_logout` write any custom code, run `Auth::logout();` and then make redirection

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete documention for authentication. Just try to use the Auth facades to accomplish your task.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

You only need to use manual authentication - the rest of the things will be taken care by the Laravel in the background.

Comment: now i update my admin_logout.now also i can able to see the dashboard

Comment: Just try to print the id of the user using Auth::user() after Auth::logout() if you get the result that means the user is still logged in.

Comment: You didnt get the user ID that means you are logged out since Auth::user() didnt print anything

Comment: yes.but if i click a button it shows the dashboard why im getting this error.how to resolve this